# Visual Studio 2022 Auto-Saving in Merge Conflict Resolution with SourceTree - How to Prevent?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 as my external diff and merge tool in SourceTree. When I encounter a merge conflict and Visual Studio's merge view opens, I'm immediately prompted to save the file. I can't interact with the merge view, and the only options are to save, not save, or cancel.

When I choose to save, Visual Studio takes everything from the local file, which is not the desired result. I have double-checked my configuration in SourceTree, and everything appears to be set up correctly.

How can I prevent Visual Studio 2022 from auto-saving and allow me to interact with the merge view during conflict resolution in SourceTree?

This is my setup in Sourcetree:
External Diff/Merge Tool: Custom
Diff / Merge Command:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Proffesional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe

Arguments:
Diff tool: "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "Source" "Target" //t
Merge tool: "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED" //m